# How to scale an image in Python?

Tags: python

```
def scaleImage(image):
    """
    A function that takes an image and makes each pixel grayscale:
    the red, blue, green components are the average of the respective
    components in each original pixel.
    """

    pix = image.getPixels()

    # How can I condense the following loop?

    newimage = Image()
    for pixel in pix:
        newpixel = ((int(pixel[0]) + int(pixel[1]) + int(pixel[2]))/3,
                    (int(pixel[0]) + int(pixel[1]) + int(pixel[2]))/3,
                    (int(pixel[0]) + int(pixel[1]) + int(pixel[2]))/3,
                     int(pixel[3]))
        newimage.setPixels(newpixel)

    return newimage
```

My task is to write a function showScale() that asks the user for an image filename, then displays both that image and its grayscale version in a window.

```
def showScale():

    filename = raw_input("The name of the image file? ")
    picture = Image.open(filename)
    newpicture = Image.open(scaleImage(picture))
    newpicture.show()
```

Question1. Should I use cs1graphics module to make it work?

Question2. How should I change my code to answer my task?

Comment: Your title is very general. I think you should edit it to be more specific.

Comment: Your grayscaling algorithm is incorrect. It's a weighted average, not a mean.

Comment: @pynator: all the questions from hkus10 seems like homework...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using [`PIL`](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

`greyscaleIm = Image.open(filename).convert("L")`

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm

Answer (score -1):

although it may be overkill depending on what your ultimate goal is. It is also possible to do it with opencv.

```
img = cv.LoadImage(image)
gray = cv.cvCreateImage ((img.width, img.height), 8, 1)
cv.cvCvtColor(img, gray, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
```

then show both with

```
cv.NamedWindow(...
cv.ShowImage(...
```